# Web API 2 - CORS - working in debug, but not in IIS express

Tags: azure, iis, cors, asp.net-web-api2, iis-express

I've been struggling with the following problem for the past couple of days:

We have a Web API project with a CORS implementation.

When I run the project locally, in debug mode, everything works.

The problem arises when I try to deploy the project to the local IIS or if I stop debugging in VS.
As soon as I try to make a request I get the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:82' is therefore not allowed access.

To further anoy me, when I deploy the API to our azure environment, everything works and I dont get the error anymore.

This is my startup.cs with my CORS config:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(buildCorsOptions());

    ConfigureAuth(app);
}

private static CorsOptions buildCorsOptions()
{
    return new CorsOptions
    {
        PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
        {
            PolicyResolver = context =>
            {
                var corsPolicy = new CorsPolicy
                {
                    AllowAnyHeader = true,
                    AllowAnyMethod = true,
                    SupportsCredentials = true
                };

                //localhosts for debugging purposes
                corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://localhost");
                corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://localhost:82");

                return Task.FromResult(corsPolicy);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Anyone that has any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

We had an endpoint returning an exception that was being executed before CORS had a chance to modify the response headers.

This made the error look like a CORS problem, but it realy was just an internal exception in our code.

Answer (score -1):

Tried several codes and config changes offered by dozens of website earlier and none worked for me (VS 2019 Community Edition  + EDGE + IISExpress).  Workaround is to just use Google Chrome instead and install the plugin called CORS Unlock. You need to install this plugin after you launch your page via VS.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-install-microsoft-cors-module-for-iis-express-7ac24e4c3bc4 Step 1 is to have CORS module on IIS Express if you don’t want to switch to full IIS.